# Update Mysql column by subtracting a value with some conditions?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have Some tables

```
id     name     points
-----------------------
1      name1      0
2      name2      15
3      name3      0
4      name4      20
```

I want to update points table by `$db->Query`

I want to subtracting 1 from points but condition is if points is greater then 0.

So when Update the table shows like that

```
id      name     points
-----------------------
1       name1      0
2       name2      14
3       name3      0
4       name4      19
```

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter?  Do you need help with the syntax for that, or just the SQL query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```sql
UPDATE yourtable
   SET points = points - 1
 WHERE points > 0
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d44a5/1)**

To execute it using mysqli extension you can do something like this

```php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');

$sql = "UPDATE yourtable
           SET points = points - 1
         WHERE points > 0";

$db->query($sql);
```

Comment: can i try this
$db->Query("UPDATE `table` SET `points`='`points` - 1' WHERE `points` > 0");

Comment: @Auhits You have not to use the single quotes in points - 1, because of this is part of the MySQL syntax.